# java random number average calculation

Tags: java, random

How do you find an average of a group of random numbers. For example, how would you find the average of, say you prompt the user for how many times they want to generate a random number and they entered 9 and you make the random number with `random = randlist.nextInt(100) + 1;`? I know you find the average by dividing the sum of the numbers by how many numbers there are, but in this case, how do you find the numbers generated by the random method and add them together and divide them by 9?

Comment: I am confused.  You have stated what you need to do, even some of the code you need, and then asked how you do it.  Can you clarify what the problem you are having is?  Can you show us the code you have so far?  I assume you know how to write a loop and ask for user input (or you can google for it)

Comment: Explain more please! As I found you must save the random numbers (9 numbers) so you can refer to them and use them for average.

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi No, you don't need to save all the numbers. All you need is their sum and how many values are in that sum.

Answer (score 3):

With:

```
double avg = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < nTimes; i++) {
    avg += randlist.nextInt(100) + 1;
}
avg /= nTimes; //This is the final average
```

Comment: it's safer to use `long` for the summing, and `double avg = (double)sum / nTimes;`